# Harvesting Energy from Gas Giants

Tags: internal-consistency, space, gas-giants

In my world, humans live on a moon of a gas giant that has extreme weather conditions.  They also:

- have crystals that can store energy.
- possess the ability to make floating islands (on which they can sustain atmosphere)
- can teleport via gates

*Edit: the crystals work like batteries.*

**How would such a society harvest the storm and wind energy of a nearby gas giant?**

Comment: Do you mean literally acquire it's substance for use? Your gates would seem to be the key. What conditions can they withstand and what are the  conditions and what's it like in the gas giant at the point in it's depth you need access to to get the substances you're after? How do the crystals absorb energy? Can they absorb heat by conduction, radiation or how? At the moment you seem to be asking about two things: the substance of the gas giant and energy, what is your objective here? We would need to understand better what you are asking.

Comment: I was thinking about more of wind and storm energy and crystals are for electrical energy like batteries. As for the gates they are purely for transportation of Cristals (batteries).

Comment: You are saying that you want to harvest the energy of a gas giant's atmosphere, but not it's matter (substance) is that right? You are also saying that the gates can transport crystals, but not floating-islands or other technology or people, is that right?

Comment: I realize that this is a flavour thing you're going for, but if you have below-cost teleportation (gates that move things from point A to point B for less energy than it'd cost to transport them the conventional way), that's an infinite energy machine and you don't _need_ a gas giant.

Comment: Crystals that store energy is as big as bottles. The teleportation is one person teleportation so person + what they can carry like a dozen of crystals or supply's for a day

Comment: Teleportation needs energy from crystals. Peoples don't use space craft because they need maintenance and they are way more  dangerous than teleportation

Comment: @AIwithstick the important question is whether teleporting, say, 1000km straight up requires less energy than the gravitational potential energy you'd have once you'd got there. If it does, then you've created an infinite energy source that is much safer and easier than visiting a gas giant. If you don't want perpetual motion machines, design your teleporters carefully.

Comment: You can ride a road on car or teleport there instantly and they would cost really close amount of energy

Comment: @Alwithstick - you may want to update the question with those stipulations.  A lot of the answers you're getting are frame changes, and I am inferring from your question as it stands that you want to get your power from the storms on the gas giant, not from its other properties.

Comment: @AIwithstick - follow-up question: you specified that they "don't use spacecraft".  Do they _have_ spacecraft?  If they don't, do gates need to be assembled at both ends of a teleportation trip?

Answer (score 4):

Moons of gas giants tend to be tidally locked. They are also [tidally heated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_heating).

[image: Tidal heating]

So there you have it. Go for thermal energy.

---

Alternatively: if you can build teleporting gates, what is keeping you from building a Dyson sphere around your star? Ditch the gas giant and go for the mother lode.

Comment: Teleportation is magic and they don't have crayz technology. That's one of the reasons they don't complex space craft

Comment: @AIwithstick making giant energy harvesting lighter-than-atmosphere structures _on a gas giant_ is pretty crazy technology, you know.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is you extract hydrogen. You can use it along with oxygen in fuel cells, or rocket fuel, or for fuel in a fusion reactor.

Fusion reactors make the most sense in my opinion. You need hydrogen-3, which is rare hydrogen isotope. You won't have to transport massive amounts of hydrogen, you'll get the most energy and since hydrogen-3 is rare, it's plausible you might need to "mine" a gas giant for it.

Of course nothing prevents you from also producing "byproducts" such as rocket fuel. At the very least you want to produce enough fuel to transport cargo to and from the gas mining station and since hydrogen is available, why not use it.

Comment: Interesting if bringing tritium out from the gravity well of a gas giant would cost less energy than using it as fusion fuel would yield?

Comment: @CongenitalOptimist making the tritium in the first place would be a massive hassle. You certainly won't be able to harvest a whole lot of it there (or indeed, anywhere).

Comment: @CongenitalOptimist There is abundance of hydrogen so if your spacecraft is using a ramjet engine (sucking hydrogen straight out of the air), it only needs to bring oxidizer (O2). Given Jupiter's gravity is 2.5g, and that the payload will be fairly small (10s to 100s  of kilos) you'll be able to do it with conventional rocket. I have no idea if that would be economical but it's not some exuberant cost.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Apparently on Earth, tritium is a byproduct of nuclear fission. In deep space you won't have access to refined fuel and running a fission plant is complicated business. I don't know how much tritium can you get from a gas giant, but given technology level somewhat similar to ours, getting it from somewhere else does not sound plausible.

Comment: @ventsyv I am not sure about the conventional rocket but the payload is of course very energy dense, in the order of 6 million times more so than gasoline: [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/363056/does-60kg-of-fusion-fuel-produce-as-much-energy-as-400-kilotonnes-of-coal). 

As we harvest the tritium then we probably also have means to use it as rocket fuel.

Comment: @ventsyv This bears little relation to the question, and really doesn't work as a frame-challenge.